# More elegant way to do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pretty simple piece of code, it just seems way to verbose though. Is there a nicer way to do this in one line? Just out of curiosity. It's in python 3.5.

```
if predictedClassification >= 0.5:
   predictedClassification = 1
else
   predictedClassification = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
predictedClassification = 1 if predictedClassification >= 0.5 else 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `if`/`else` statement in one line as follows:

```
predictedClassification = 1 if predictedClassification >= 0.5 else 0
```

Answer (score 3):

With an [`if-else` conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
predictedClassification = 1 if predictedClassification >= 0.5 else 0
```

The result equals `1` if the expression is `True` and 0 otherwise.

```
predictedClassification = 10

predictedClassification = 1 if predictedClassification >= 0.5 else 0

print(predictedClassification)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an old BASIC programmers trick for rounding:

```
rounded = int(float_num + 0.5)
```

This relies on your `int` function just chopping off the decimal point. In the case of Python and your specific example:

```
predictedClassification = int(predictedClassification + 0.5)
```

*NOTE:* Be careful (and run a test) about negatives. If your predictedClassification is negative, do you want to round/truncate towards zero or away from zero? That is, does a PC of -.5 become -1 or 0? This is a domain issue (meaning you have to decide) but the language may make things complicated for you.

Comment: I was thinking about providing an `int` rounding answer by adding `0.5` as well, to drop the conditional. But then I thought what if the number is greater equal to `1.5`, then it rounds to `2`, or greater, and not `1`. That and what you mentioned in your note lead me to not. Good answer though.